# Cannot cast to type alias

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created a type alias `gp` for the PostgreSQL type `money`, and I can't figure out from the documentation how I'm supposed to use this.

I've set up a test table (and database):

```sql
CREATE TYPE gp AS (amt money);
CREATE TABLE test (val gp PRIMARY KEY);
```

But no matter how I try to insert rows, it fails

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1); -- column "val" is of type gp but expression is of type integer
INSERT INTO test VALUES ((1)); -- column "val" is of type gp but expression is of type integer
INSERT INTO test VALUES (CAST (1 AS gp)); -- cannot cast type integer to gp
INSERT INTO test VALUES (CAST (CAST (1 AS money) AS gp)); -- cannot cast type money to gp
INSERT INTO test VALUES ((amt=1)); -- column "amt" does not exist
INSERT INTO test VALUES ((amt=1)::gp); -- column "amt" does not exist
```

From what I understand, the `gp` type should be an alias: `gp::money::numeric`, so why can't it cast from `money` to an alias of `money`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a row constructor:

```
insert into test values (row(1));
```

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

> The key word ROW is optional when there is more than one expression in the list.

Note, that a composite type with a single component makes a little sense. You can use a [domain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html) instead.

Comment: The idea is I can make a type `cp` that's 1/00 of an `sp` which is 1/100 of a `gp`. domains may be better (gotta read up on that) but rest assured; I did have a plan.

Comment: I don't think that the approach (by types) is a good direction, though I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Maybe a new question about the whole idea would be helpful.

Comment: Asking "how do I accomplish x?" on SO is a recipe for banning. I want to use types because by defining an input_function and output_function I can do e.g. `INSERT INTO test VALUES (2gp), (10cp), (6sp);` and `SELECT 100cp;` -> `1sp`. As far as I can tell, there's no equivalent to those two functions for DOMAINs

Comment: I see. But you cannot do this by a composite type, you have to create a new base type with the functions coded in C (this is a kind of extending Postgres).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm looking at. This question is just a toy exercise, the beginnings of the new type.

Comment: Not perfect, but progress [in my GitHub project](https://github.com/ocket8888/dndDB/blob/master/gp.c)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below snippet

> ```
> CREATE TYPE gp AS (amt money);
> CREATE TABLE test (val gp PRIMARY KEY);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES (row(1::money))
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> 1 rows affected
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=4facfd63bd4a68095ff7c326c490887e)*